# Combine JSON objects in Ruby, and output to CSV

Tags: ruby, json, csv

Let's say I have two JSON objects (call them 'websites' and 'links'). I need to end up with both objects in a single CSV (ideally in separate columns).

I'm working with something like this:

```
File.open("file.json", "w") do |f|
   combined = [websites, links]
   f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(combined))
end
```

And then I'm using the Ruby gem json2csv to convert this file to a CSV. But when I do, I get the following error:

```
error: undefined method 'keys' for #<Array:0x007fea8a8e33f8>
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. When I look in file.json, it appears to be structured like this: [{websites}, {links}]. From my limited knowledge of JSON, I think that's right, but I could easily be wrong.

Also, I know this won't get me separate columns in the CSV. If anyone has an answer for that part, major bonus points.

EDIT: JSON examples included below; error message changed after minor fix on my end.

websites:

```
{
  "uri": "https://v1/websites",
  "id": 28235674,
  "background": null,
  "createdDate": 1399585684000,
  "lastActivityDate": 1430682494000,
  "lastCommunicationDate": 1430682494000,
  "lastNonCommunicationChronicleDate": 1430330886000,
  "lastModifiedDate": 1449263116000,
  "lastViewedDate": 1421429034000,
  "preferredContactType": null,
  "rss": "",
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "email": "",
      "type": "Work"
    },
    {
      "email": "",
      "type": "Work"
    },
    {
      "email": "",
      "type": "Work"
    },
    {
      "email": "not found",
      "type": "Work"
    }
  ],
  "phoneNumbers": [

  ],
  "streetAddresses": [

  ],
  "socialNetworks": [
    {
      "profileUrl": "http://twitter.com",
      "name": "Twitter"
    },
    {
      "profileUrl": "http://www.facebook.com",
      "name": "Facebook"
    },
    {
      "profileUrl": "http://plus.google.com",
      "name": "GooglePlus"
    },
    {
      "profileUrl": "http://www.linkedin.com",
      "name": "LinkedIn"
    },
{
  "profileUrl": "http://twitter.com",
  "name": "Twitter"
}
  ],
  "contactUrls": [

  ],
  "tags": [
    "tag1",
    "tag2"
  ],
  "mostRecentActivity": "https://v1/history",
  "mostRecentChronicle": "https://v1/history",
  "mostRecentCommunication": "https://v1/history",
  "mostRecentNonCommunicationChronicle": "https://v1/history",
  "projectStates": "https://v1/websites",
  "history": "https://v1/history",
  "customFieldValues": [

  ],
  "name": "",
  "primaryDomain": "",
  "domains": [
    ""
  ],
  "associatedPeople": "https://v1/people",
  "payments": "https://payments",
  "links": "https://v1/links",
  "type": "https://v1/websites"
}
```

links:

```
{
  "uri": "https://v1/links/custom_fields",
  "id": 15529329,
  "value": "Name",
  "backgroundColor": null,
  "customField": "https://v1/links/custom_fields"
}
```

combined output:

```
[
  {
    "uri": "https://v1/websites",
    "id": 28235674,
    "background": null,
    "createdDate": 1399585684000,
    "lastActivityDate": 1430682494000,
    "lastCommunicationDate": 1430682494000,
    "lastNonCommunicationChronicleDate": 1430330886000,
    "lastModifiedDate": 1449263116000,
    "lastViewedDate": 1421429034000,
    "preferredContactType": null,
    "rss": "",
    "emailAddresses": [
      {
        "email": "",
        "type": "Work"
      },
      {
        "email": "",
        "type": "Work"
      },
      {
        "email": "",
        "type": "Work"
      },
      {
        "email": "not found",
        "type": "Work"
      }
    ],
    "phoneNumbers": [

    ],
    "streetAddresses": [

    ],
    "socialNetworks": [
      {
        "profileUrl": "http://twitter.com/",
        "name": "Twitter"
      },
      {
        "profileUrl": "http://www.facebook.com",
        "name": "Facebook"
      },
      {
        "profileUrl": "http://plus.google.com",
        "name": "GooglePlus"
      },
      {
        "profileUrl": "http://www.linkedin.com/",
        "name": "LinkedIn"
      },
      {
        "profileUrl": "http://twitter.com/",
        "name": "Twitter"
      }
    ],
    "contactUrls": [

    ],
    "tags": [
      "tag1",
      "tag2"
    ],
    "mostRecentActivity": "https://v1/history/",
    "mostRecentChronicle": "https://v1/history/",
    "mostRecentCommunication": "https://v1/history/",
    "mostRecentNonCommunicationChronicle": "https://v1/history/",
    "projectStates": "https://v1/websites/",
    "history": "https://v1/history",
    "customFieldValues": [

    ],
    "name": "",
    "primaryDomain": "",
    "domains": [
      ""
    ],
    "associatedPeople": "https://v1/people",
    "links": "https://v1/links",
    "type": "https://v1/websites"
  },
  {
    "uri": "https://links/custom_fields",
    "id": 15529329,
    "value": "Name",
    "backgroundColor": null,
    "customField": "https://links/custom_fields"
  }
]
```

Comment: We're going to need to see the actual JSON.  Scramble the URLs if you need to, but keep the format.

Comment: What is "the JSON object junction"? Please edit your question to include the actual JSON data around the position the error occurs and the actual error message.

Comment: Share the `websites` and `links` JSON examples

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.pretty_generate()` is expecting a hash and you are passing an array of 2 hashes. Start with: `combined.map { |c| f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(c)) }` and then mapping them into your CSV should be as easy as following the CSV documentation.

Comment: Hm, this still doesn't work using json2csv, but if you could provide code for an alternative you have in mind, I'd hugely appreciate it. The output now is formatted like this: {websites}{links} (no comma or anything between the two objects). Is that correct?